# Amazon Gateway API with Lambda - Could not parse request body into json

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I seem to be getting a issue with Amazon Gateway API not liking my sent params for example.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://tibqwxuqoh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getitems",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            "device": "test",
            "datetime": "1446757400919"
        },
        success: function (returnhtml) {
            console.log(returnhtml);
            $("#result").append("DOES NOT WORK - <br>" + JSON.stringify(returnhtml));
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://tibqwxuqoh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getitems",
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        success: function (returnhtml) {
            console.log(returnhtml);
            $("#result").append("<br>WORKS ???? - <br>" + JSON.stringify(returnhtml));
        }
    });
```

Here is a working example.
http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/4315/

Can someone let me know why it wont let me send params every time i add a parameter i get this error.

```
{
    Type = User;
    message = "Could not parse request body into json.";
}
```

OK THIS WORKS BUT SEEMS A BIT WEIRD TO ME.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "https://tibqwxuqoh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getitems",
        type: "POST",
        data: "{\"device\": \"test\",\"datetime\": \"1446757444524\"}",
        success: function (returnhtml) {
            console.log(returnhtml);
            $("#result").append("WORKS - <br>" + JSON.stringify(returnhtml));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in how you send the data to API Gateway.
Without knowing the details of your API configuration I am guessing that you have a Request Mapping setup for application/json.
jQuery will by default post your data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded but you want to send it as json.

You can do this without having to fiddle too much with the data yourself:

```
var requestParams = {
    url: "https://tibqwxuqoh.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/getitems",
    method: "POST,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        "device": "test",
        "datetime": "1446757400919"
    });
};
var request = $.ajax(requestParams);
```

The key here is JSON.stringify() and telling jQuery that the dataType is json as well as setting the contentType to application/json.